# How can I create model instance with CreateAPIView by post JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I made StudyGroup model with users. If I want to make StudyGroup with CreateAPIView, what data I have to post to create StudyGroup model?

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class StudyGroup(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='study_groups')

from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'study_groups')

class StudyGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = StudyGroup
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'users')

from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class StudyGroupCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = StudyGroup.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudyGroupSerializer


urlpatterns = [
    path('create_study_group/', views.StudyGroupCreate.as_view()),
]
```

Posted datas ("name": "created_group" was in body, and auth was OK)

```
"users": [2, 3]     // 2, 3 is userid in DB
"users": 2

"users": ["A", "B"] // A, B is username in DB
"users": "A"
```

Response status=400

```
{
    "users": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `users = UserSerializer(many=True)` in the study group serializer means it is expecting an array of user objects as defined in the user serializer. To post users, it is advisable to add another field in the serilializer that is write only while the one you defined should be read only. Something like this:

```
class StudyGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), required=True, write_only=True)
    # these ids get converted to actual users after validation
    class Meta:
        model = StudyGroup
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'users', 'user_ids')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_ids = validated_data.pop('user_ids')
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for user in user_ids:
            instance.users.add(user)
        return instance
```